# Off canvas menu with Foundation 5 doesn't work

Tags: menu, zurb-foundation

I followed closely [instructions from Foundation 5 doc about canvas menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html#). I obtain no JS error, yet it doesn't work. Clicking on the link does nothing:

[Demo page](http://goo.gl/cA3drI)

Why does it not work?

Comment: Becuase you're hosting this on a site tagged as having malware. Just use codepen, jsbin, like everyone else on the modern internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the end of your body :

```
   <script>
      $(document).foundation();
   </script>
```

From the doc : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

> Initialize Foundation After you have included the Foundation
>   JavaScript, just add a simple call to initialize all plugins on your
>   page.
>
> We recommend that you initialize Foundation at the end of the page

Comment: Wow thanks, it works but I'm not sure to understand why. I understand the recommendation but executing $(document).foundation(); in the <head> should still work...

Comment: I'm new to Foundation and somehow missed that it needs to be activated like this. I've spent so long trying to figure out why the menu was not behaving very well. Thanks!